# Detect which NSTableView is active

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, appkit, nssplitview

I have an NSSplitView showing two NSTableView instances. I need to detect which table view has become "active" (of focused), which means the one that the user has clicked. I need to know that because each table view acts as a source list for another view that shows the content of the selected row(s). This other view is shared for both tables.

I could do it by subclassing NSTableView and reacting to `mouseDown:` or another method but it I'd rather avoid subclassing just for that. I also don't want to track any NSWindow event just to know if the user has clicked one of the tables (I'd rather subclass NSTableView).

Currently, I use the delegate method `tableViewSelectionDidChange:`, but this method is, obviously, only called when the selected row changes. I need to know that a table becomes active even if the selected row hasn't changed.

Observing the `clickedRow` property of the table views doesn't appear to work. If may not be KVO compliant.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the window is the active window you can check the first responder `window.firstResponder == tableView1`

Comment: Do you want to detect which table view is active or do you want to detect when a table view becomes focused?

Comment: Hi @Willeke, I want to detect when a table view becomes active, so as to react to the change. I don't want to determine which is active at a random point in time. Which is why the suggestion by @vadian isn't really useful for me. Right now, I'm subclassing NSTableView to send a message to its delegate when it becomes first responder (I override `becomesFirstResponder`). I may stick to this solution if I can't find a simpler one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the most convenient solution I found was to take advantage of the fact that `NSTableView` is a subclass of `NSControl`. So just like NSButton it can send action messages when clicked (upon mouse up).
For each tableView, I wired its "action" to the same ibaction selector of my controller object in interface builder.
The controller identifies the sender and acts accordingly.
No need to subclass NSTableView.